# Change style of md-tab-header in Angular2

Tags: css, angular

I'm currently working on a project which I retrieved from a previous collegue. Hence, I'm discovering it bit by bit and am trying to fix its issues.

There is a md-tab-header with a .mat-tab-header class that I would like to target with my css to change its style so I tried something like:

```
.mat-tab-header{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

or

```
 md-tab-header.mat-tab-header{
  background-color: blue !important;
```

`}`

I placed this code in the component.css of a specific page because I don't want it to affect the whole project (otherwise I would have put it in my HTML). I guess my problem is that I cannot override Angular's style this way.
How should I proceed?

I guess the cleanest way would be to change the architecture but it is such a small thing that I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: You probably need to affect on '.mat-tab-label'

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The thing is the label is a block with a size to the word it contains but I would like to target the container which is the full width of the area from which I'm trying to put a background on.

Comment: I don't see any problem with styling on 'md-tab-header.mat-tab-header'. Probably you are wrong with place 'component.css'. If you'll put the style in 'styles.css' it will work. Try to check this.

Comment: It works but the thing is, it applies everywhere :s I would like to find a way to make it only on one page. That is why I was trying to put it in the component.css .

Comment: I found a way thanks to your idea. Maybe it was so simple I couldn't see it haha to make it work on a specific page I just had to put an id over a parent container to target it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ViewEncapsulation.None in your component declaration and add styles to your css file

@Component({
  ....
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})